# I have had my bearded dragon for 5 years and dark patches appear now?

Tags: safety

What does this mean please someone answer and I am so nervous and might freak out because I do not know what to do. I have looked multiple time to see if it was skin, but it was not. Also this just appeared on him recently. Legs and tail.

Comment: Can you post photos along with details of his setup?